# Jupyter notebook icon won't get removed from app menu after I uninstalled it. How do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

I uninstalled jupyter notebook using pip uninstall, and I also checked / removed all of the jupyter notebook files from usr/bin , usr/local/bin, snap/bin. But I can't seem to get rid of this Jupyter Notebook icon - which lost the .ico file after un-installation but it won't go from the application menu. And I also tried a .desktop file that's responsible for the icon but couldn't find one for jupyter.

[image]

It's also there in the settings => applications menu. it's just a non-functional leftover that I can't seem to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Just a newbie with computers and everything electric, so please be kind...

I would suggest removing jupyter-nbclassic.desktop from /home//.local/share/applications.

In the same directory you might want to edit mimeinfo.cache and remove the entry application/x-ipynb+json=jupyter-nbclassic.desktop;.

Hope it works, and respect best practices... and why not people.

Did work on PopOS 22.04.